# Add Contacts to Campaign from Joined Report

Tags: reporting, campaign, joined-reports

I have a joined report that shows a list of Contact email addresses that I'd like to add to a Campaign.  However, because of the way the objects are structured (Contact > Junction Object > Membership > Objects I need), it's not possible to create a Contact report (that would display the Add to Campaign button).

Is there a way to quickly assign all of these people to a Campaign?  Or would it require some crazy Visualforce etc?  And if so, where should I start digging in!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show these contacts then you can use custom report type + join report to show this data.

If you want the ability to select contact and add them to campaign on click of button then you will need to write VF + apex code.